# I am unable to see the PROPER contents of the array I am returning. Why?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class BubbleSort {

    public static int[] bubbleSort(int[]arrayInput) {

        boolean swapped = true;
        int tmp = 0;

        while(swapped) {

            swapped = false;//We don't know if the array is pre-sorted

            for(int i = 0; i<(arrayInput.length)-1; i++) {

                if(arrayInput[i] > arrayInput[i+1]) {

                    tmp = arrayInput[i];
                    arrayInput[i] = arrayInput[i+1];
                    arrayInput[i+1] = tmp;

                    swapped = true;//Unsorted array - check again
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayInput;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        int[]unsorted = {13, 2, 11, 6, 5, 15};
        int[]finalArray = bubbleSort(unsorted);
        System.out.println(finalArray);
    }
}
```

I am completely unsure as to why I am getting a bunch of nonsense returned back to me. The code compiles no problem. I am quite positive in its correctness. Can anybody help me produce an array of integers, instead of garbage. Thanks

Comment: What output are you seeing vs what you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print values contained inside the Array use [Arrays#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) . 
Change

```
System.out.println(finalArray);
```

to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to output them one by one. Something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayInput.length; i++) {         
    System.out.println(arrayInput[i]);
}
```

Right now you are printing array as an object.

Array extends Object, which have toString() method, that is called in your situation

According to javadoc

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())